# How to find relations/properties for SPARQL queries

Tags: sparql

I started learning **SPARQL** and try to perform some queries on **DBPedia**. The issue I have is I don't know what relations/properties already exist, and most importantly what are the prefixes I need to use in my queries.

I did find **foaf** through DBPedia's page (*dbpedia.org/sparql > namespace prefixes*), but most links show weird results or don't work at all. I was wondering if there's a page where I can maybe search for a property and it would return the prefix, or at least a page where there are all the existing properties and associated prefixes that are most commonly used.

Comment: PRefixes are not part of an RDF dataset, it's just a convenience feature of some serialization formats like Turtle and so it it for SPARQL queries. That said, there is no SPARQL query to return prefixes out of an RDF dataset. Anything beyond is triple store specific. And you can always use full URI for the properties, classes, resources in RDF.